# How to bounce an object inside circular bounds?

Tags: java, math, libgdx

In my game i have circular bounds and inside the bounds i have an object that is supposed to bounce around, but for some reason it does not bounce. My code is shown below.

```
public void checkBouncer(Bouncer b){
    float x = b.getPosition().x;
    float y = b.getPosition().y;
    float cx = Constants.CENTER_X - b.getWidth() / 2;
    float cy = Constants.CENTER_Y - b.getHeight() / 2;
    float dx = Math.abs(x - cx);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - cy);
    float r = (Constants.PARAMETER_RADIUS - 45) - b.getHeight();

    // check collision between bounds and bouncer
    if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) >= (r * r)) {
        // original velocity vector
        Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(b.getVelocity().x, b.getVelocity().y);

        // normal vector
        Vector2 n = new Vector2(
                Constants.CENTER_X - b.getPosition().x,
                Constants.CENTER_Y - b.getPosition().y
        );

        // normalize
        if (n.len() > 0) n = n.nor();

        // dot product
        float dot = v1.x * n.x + v1.y * n.y;

        // reflected vector values
        v2.x = v1.x - 2 * dot * n.x;
        v2.y = v1.y - 2 * dot * n.y;
    }
    // set new velocity
    b.setVelocity(v2);
}
```

The object that i want to bounce starts out by moving in the direction it is facing, the update method is shown below:

```
public void update(float delta) {
    direction.x = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
    direction.y = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));

    if (direction.len() > 0) {
        direction = direction.nor();
    }

    velocity.x = direction.x * speed;
    velocity.y = direction.y * speed;

    position.x += velocity.x * delta;
    position.y += velocity.y * delta;

    circle.set(position.x + width / 2, position.y + height / 2, width / 2);
}
```

But if i invert the angle on collision its kind of working but it's jittery and does not always bounce back on collision. The code for that is here:

```
if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) >= (r * r)) {
        b.setAngle(-b.getAngle());
}
```

Please i need help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163635/bouncing-a-ball-within-a-circle

Answer (score 0):

Emm... You have got right velocity vector components after reflection here:

```
 v2.x = v1.x - 2 * dot * n.x; 
 and same for y
```

Why do you need to use angle?

If direction angle is really needed for some reason, get its value as

```
angle = atan2(v2.y, v2.x)
```

Comment: i used the angle just to test if the collision works, i tried using your suggestion but it's not working.

Comment: What you mean - "it's not working" ? Wrong angle? Wrong system behavior?

Comment: is bouncing at wrong angles, some times it's going right through.

Comment: Your  condition` if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) >= (r * r)) ` might produce bad results if position occurs far out of the circle. Better approach - precalculate collision place and time.